# Google Maps - Hide destination marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to display some hit markers on google maps, and display a route from start to finish.

I've got the route displaying, but my origin and destination have the exact same co-ordinates, causing the destination marker (marker 'D') to overlap the origin marker, this is displayed below:

[Waypoint markers on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epHVZ.jpg)

Ideally i'd like to hide just the destination marker, but I have absolutely no idea how to suppress an individual marker.

#### The displayRoute function

```
     displayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    let numberOfHits = this.geo.Data.rows.length - 1;
    let firstHit = this.geo.Data.rows[numberOfHits];
    let lastHit = this.geo.Data.rows[0];
    let wayPoint, i;
    let wayPointsArray = [];

    this.checkForDuplicates('Id', this.geo.Data.rows);

    for (i = 1; i < numberOfHits; i++) {
      wayPoint = this.geo.Data.rows[i];

      if (this.duplicatesArr.indexOf(wayPoint.Id) === -1) {
        wayPointsArray.unshift({
          location: {
            lat: wayPoint.latitude,
            lng: wayPoint.longitude
          }
        });
      } else if (this.duplicatesArr.indexOf(wayPoint.Id) > -1) {
        console.log('wayPoint', wayPoint.Id, 'has already been hit')
      }
    }

    let request = {
      origin: {
        lat: firstHit.latitude,
        lng: firstHit.longitude
      },
      destination: {
        lat: lastHit.latitude,
        lng: lastHit.longitude
      },
      waypoints: wayPointsArray,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    if((request.origin.lat == request.destination.lat) && (request.origin.lng == request.destination.lng)) {
      // Code to hide destination marker
    }

    directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    });
  }
```

#### The geo data

```
this.geo = {
     "Data": {
      "records": 7,
      "total": 1,
      "page": 1,
      "rows": [
        {
          "Id": 2778,
          "latitude": 51.509697,
          "longitude": -2.2
        },
        {
          "Id": 53,
          "latitude": 50.980598,
          "longitude": -1.36827
        },
        {
          "Id": 2750,
          "latitude": 51.152599,
          "longitude": -1.34676
        },
        {
          "Id": 2778,
          "latitude": 51.509697,
          "longitude": -2.2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

My apologies, for clarity here is where I've created the directionsDisplay:

```
  createMap() {
let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
map.fitBounds(bounds);

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
this.displayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
```

};

This is used just before the displayRoute() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DirectionsRendererOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions.suppressMarkers) has a `suppressMarkers` property.

This will hide both origin and destination markers.

You can then simply add your own marker at the origin coordinates. An example based on the code you posted:

```
if ((request.origin.lat == request.destination.lat) && (request.origin.lng == request.destination.lng)) {

  // Code to hide destination marker

  var rendererOptions = {
    suppressMarkers: true,
  };

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(request.origin.lat, request.origin.lng),
    map: map
  });

} else {

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
}

directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
});
```

You didn't post your complete code, so the above implies that you remove your (not included) initialization of `var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, doesn't suppress markers affect the waypoints as-well, not just the origin & destination markers?

Comment: True. It will. But you can apply the same technique to waypoints (create your own markers). `suppressMarkers` is the only documented way to remove any (and all) markers. Or... don't use the renderer and do it all manually (render the Polyline and whatever markers you need). But I don't see any benefit.